# How do I reassign parameters in a Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to Jenkins and groovy scripting. I'm trying to reassign the parameters in the Jenkins script.

I tried the following

```
def reasignParams() {
    if(params.B == '') {
       params.B = params.A
    }
}

pipeline{
    parameters {
         string(name: 'A', defaultValue: '1.1', description: "Master Value")
         string(name: 'B', defaultValue: '', description: "Slave value")
    }
}
```

After running the above Jenkins pipeline script (groovy), I ran into the following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

The alternative that I thought to this is as below

```
def reasignParams() {
        if(params.B == '') {
           def temp = params.A
           # use temp variable instead of params.B; But this is inconvenient
        }
    }
```

I would like to learn if there is a way to reassign parameters in the Jenkins pipeline script? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` object in Jenkins Pipeline does not support `write` operations on its member variables. You can only initially assign them in the `parameters` directive (think of it like a constructor in that sense). If you want to reassign parameter values, then you do indeed need to make a deep copy like the following:

```
newParams = [:]
newParams.A = params.A
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you point me to the documentation for the shallow copy? I couldn't find it and I would like to read more about this.

Comment: @ChandanNaik I confused myself and actually meant "deep copy". Some basic info at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear, I needed the documentation for the deep copy in the Jenkins pipeline script. 
I couldn't find the usage/syntax: newParams = [:]

Comment: @ChandanNaik `[:]` is not a deep copy in Jenkins Pipeline. It is an empty `Map` constructor in Groovy.